# AWK not printing

Tags: bash, awk

I was wondering why this `awk` command line is not printing `FILENAME`.

```
WORD=abrego
NWORD=${#WORD}
awk -F", " -v var3=$NWORD -v var2="$WORD" -v var1="colombia" \
'gsub(/^c1 \[[^]]*\]/,",") \
$NF==var1 && (var3==length($(NF-2)) || var3==length($(NF-1))) && ($(NF-2)==var2 || $(NF-1)==var2) \
{print FILENAME}' file*
```

`file1`:

```
c1 [gaston zamora-abrego, j.] univ nacl colombia sede medellin, dept ciencias forestales, medellin, colombia
```

`file2`:

```
c1 [zamora-abrego, joan g.] univ nacl colombia, dept ciencias forest, grp ecol  conservac fauna silvestre, sede medellin, colombia
```

`file3`:

```
c1 [gaston zamora-abrego, j.] univ nacl colombia, dept ciencias forestales, fac ciencias agr, medellin , antioquia, colombia
```

`file4`:

```
c1 [perez, maritza] abrego, norte de santander, colombia
```

**Expected Output**

```
file4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gsub` function in your code needs to execute first to make other conditions work.

This should work:

```
awk -F", " -v var3=$NWORD -v var2="$WORD" -v var1="colombia" '{gsub(/^c1 \[[^]]*\]/,",")} 
  $NF==var1 && (var3==length($(NF-2)) || var3==length($(NF-1))) && 
    ($(NF-2)==var2 || $(NF-1)==var2) {print FILENAME}' file*
```

Comment: Congratulations on 200k points, by the way. Just one year for the last 100k - excellent work!